# How can I put the indexs in descending order in C++ without using std?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

The results contain an index like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and these are the number of the players and I use cin to get their points like 10,0,2,0,9,0,23,0.
I would like to cout the number of the players in descending order when their point are not 0.
the result must be 6,0,4 2.
I only can make the points in descending order. How can I make this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ int results[8];

    for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
    { 
        cin >> results[i];
    } 
        
    int change;
    for( int i = 0; i < M-1; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = i+1; j < M; j++ )
        {
            if( results[i] < results[j] )
            {
                change = results[i];
                results[i] = results[j];
                results[j] = change;
            }

         }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::sort` with a custom comparator?

Answer (score 1):

You make your life 10 times easier if you create a structure to hold the player id and score:

```
struct Player
{
    int id;
    int score;
};
```

Then all you need to do is sort and skip scores of `0` in the output:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Player> players{
        {0, 10},
        {1, 0},
        {2, 2},
        {3, 0},
        {4, 9},
        {5, 0},
        {6, 23},
        {7, 0}
    };

    std::sort(players.begin(), players.end(),
             [] (auto p1, auto p2) { return p1.score > p2.score; });

    for (const auto& player : players)
    {
        if (player.score != 0)
            std::cout << player.id << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

```
6 0 4 2
```

Comment: I can not use a struct ,because the players id and points are changeable.

Comment: @teki2021 you can change data stored in `struct`s, so you need to expand on your statement as for *why* you cannot use them

Comment: Because a tester will test my program and it is working the datas which are given by the standard input.

Comment: You can populate the data with something by setting  cin >> score; players[i].score = score; and players[i].id = i;

Comment: Of course you can use struct and I strongly believe you should. I hardcoded the values because reading the value is not the problem you are asking about. Use [`vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to push elements to the vector as you are reading them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `std` (other than `cin` and `cout`) this turns pretty much into C code:

- Read each input, filtering out zero values.
- For non-zero inputs, walk the `results` array, use the index in the `results` array to access the value in the `inputs` array, and stop if that value is smaller than the current input.
- Keep that `results` index, `j`, as it will be the position where you will have to place the current input's index.
- Move all elements from that index until the end of the `results` array up one position (this is, towards the end of the array).
- Write the current input's index, `i`, at `results[j]`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/ndhd3jG5E)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout

int main ()
{
    int inputs[8];
    int results[8];
    size_t results_size{0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> inputs[i];

        int current_input{inputs[i]};

        // Nothing to do with inputs equal to zero
        if (current_input == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Kind of upper bound in results
        int j{0};
        for (; j < results_size and current_input <= inputs[results[j]]; j++);

        // Make room for new index in results
        for (int k = results_size; k > j; k--)
        {
            results[k] = results[k-1];
        }

        results[j] = i;
        results_size++;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < results_size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << results[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```